# Way to dequeue multiple cells in UIcollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

based on the screen shot, I will have a big collectionview to contain few cells (with colors). All cell will display only one time in the view except for the green one.The green one will display an array of users.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.item == 0{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: topfeatureCellIndent, for: indexPath) as! topFeatureCell
            //configure if needed
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.item == 1{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userCellIdent, for: indexPath) as! featureUserContainerViewCell
            cell.featureUsers = featureUser
            cell.selectUserdelegate = self
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.item == 2{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ticketLabelIdent, for: indexPath) as! ticketLabelCell
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.item == 3{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: whosgoingIdent, for: indexPath) as! whoGoingCell
            cell.config(withTimer: timeleft)
            return cell
        }
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: allUserCellIdent, for: indexPath) as! allUserCell
            let index = indexPath.item - 4
            let user = allPartyUserArr![index]
            cell.config(withUser: user)
            return cell
```

The way I need to display the last cell is by implement the code above but I think its not correct, because what if I want to add in other cells after displaying all the cells, is there any better way to dequeue the cell properly?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why not use different sections for the different types?

Comment: I am new to swift, can you show me how to display them in different sections? Thanks bro

Comment: Check this tutorial : https://www.raywenderlich.com/136161/uicollectionview-tutorial-reusable-views-selection-reordering

Comment: @Amit I don't think the tutorial provide me info similar to what I want, because they mainly focus on header and selection.

Comment: @MuhammadNayab any guide on how to implement sections properly?

Comment: @karenr I have tried to post an Answer Please see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use 2 Sections in UICollectionView.
keep all the one-time visible cells in section 0 and the cells which will represent array for users in section 1

This is how you can set number of sections

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
return 2
}
```

To set Header of each section you can implement below functions and set any size for your header. CGSizeMake(0, 0) will hide the Header

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width : 0, height : 0)  // Header size
}
```

then number of items in each section

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 if section == 0 {
        return 4
    }
    else {
        users.count
    }
//return (section == 0) ? 4 : users.count
}
```

to display cell

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


 if indexPath.section == 0 {
 // Based on Your implementation
          if indexPath.item == 0{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: topfeatureCellIndent, for: indexPath) as! topFeatureCell
        //configure if needed
        return cell
    }else if indexPath.item == 1{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userCellIdent, for: indexPath) as! featureUserContainerViewCell
        cell.featureUsers = featureUser
        cell.selectUserdelegate = self
        return cell
    }else if indexPath.item == 2{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ticketLabelIdent, for: indexPath) as! ticketLabelCell
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.item == 3{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: whosgoingIdent, for: indexPath) as! whoGoingCell
        cell.config(withTimer: timeleft)
        return cell
    } else {
     return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

 }else{
         //make sure the identifier of your cell for second section
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: allUserCellIdent, for: indexPath) as! allUserCell
       // populate your user cell here
        return cell
  }
```

}

Comment: bro can you explain abit on "return (section == 0) ? 4 : users.count", I dont get it

Comment: I just used ternary operator. see the edited answer. In case of section 0 we are having 4 cells(one-time display) . In case of section 1 we will return cells as per number of users to display. (I am assuming "users" is our array where users exist)

Comment: thanks man...I got another issue is the the cellforitem return me an error, "Missing return in a function expected to return 'UICollectionViewCell'"

Comment: check your if/else statements You must return a cell in all cases. Otherwise you will get this error

Comment: I am using exactly the one you provided, I think the if else is correct, weird though

Comment: in collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) , in section 0 , we have only if/else if statements. So we need to add an "else" as well(at the end, if no condition met still we have to return a cell). See the edited answer

Comment: I got error also on 
 let index = indexPath.item
            let user = allPartyUserArr[index]
            cell.config(withUser: user)

the index is out of range. I dont know why the error happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171440/discussion-between-muhammad-nayab-and-karenr).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the number of sections in `CollectionView` like this :

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 5
}
```

Set number of items in each `section` :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch section {
    case 0:
        return 1
    default:
        return 3
    }
}
```

Number of items you can set according to the `section`.

and for `cells` in each `section` :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: topfeatureCellIndent, for: indexPath) as! topFeatureCell
        //configure if needed
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userCellIdent, for: indexPath) as! featureUserContainerViewCell
        cell.featureUsers = featureUser
        cell.selectUserdelegate = self
        return cell
    case 2:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ticketLabelIdent, for: indexPath) as! ticketLabelCell
        return cell
    case 3:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: topfeatureCellIndent, for: indexPath) as! topFeatureCell
        //configure if needed
        return cell
    case 4:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: whosgoingIdent, for: indexPath) as! whoGoingCell
        cell.config(withTimer: timeleft)
        return cell
    default:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: allUserCellIdent, for: indexPath) as! allUserCell
        let index = indexPath.item - 4
        let user = allPartyUserArr![index]
        cell.config(withUser: user)
        return cell
    }

}
```

Hope this helps or else you can google for more better tutorials and solutions.

Comment: bro so you think 5 sections is better than just 2 right?

Comment: I am giving you an implementation of using different sections depending on the code you added in the question. You can change it according to your requirement.

Comment: @muhammadnayab answer is also a nice way to implement.